# Print all the names inside a string array

Tags: java

I'm practicing Java and I have a question about printing all values inside a String array. I would need to print everything inside the String arrays I have created.

I can't seem to make "Arrays.toString" to work in my code and I don't want to have to point out each value inside the array. Is there a way I can print them all at once?

```
public class MyCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] majority = {"Congrats, you may enter!", " Awesome!"};
        String[] minority = {"I'm sorry, you are too young.", " Ah that's too bad!"};   

        int permition = 17;
        boolean authorization = (permition >= 18);

        if (authorization == true) {
            System.out.println(majority[0] + majority[1]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(minority[0] + minority[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

So, if the person is above or equal to 18, the result should be "Congrats, you may enter! Awesome!", or if below 18 "I'm sorry, you are too young. Ah that's too bad!".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array

Comment: If you don't like how Arrays.toString looks like, you can always loop over the array with `for(String x: xs)` and then print them one by one.

Comment: Or use String#join https://stackoverflow.com/a/34441961/14955

Comment: You could try: `String toDisplay = Arrays.toString(majority); toDisplay = toDisplay.substring(1, toDisplay.length() - 1); System.out.println(toDisplay);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
List<String>majorities = 
Arrays.asList(majority);
List<String>minorities = 
Arrays.asList(minority);
String str_majority = String.join("", 
majorities);
String str_minority = String.join("", 
minorities);

String final = str_majority + 
str_minority
```

Comment: Why make it into a list? `join` can take the arrays directly.